# Click event using the on() function in jQuery is not working when I target an event with an ID in replace of DOCUMENT or BODY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery Click Event that recently stopped working!  It;s a really big project with hundreds of files so I could of easily changed it this past week and not realized it now that I see it is a problem.

Below is the most basic example if the Click Event in question.  Now I could of easily had it using `document` or `body` as the very 1st item last week and then I changed it to target an ID that is closer to the actual target for my click event.

It seems like I was trying to improve that performance after reading that I should use an ID that is closer to the item that needs the click event instead of using `document` or `body`.  With that in mind, I think in the past couple weeks I probably switched this out with this ID of `#taskWrap` to replace something like `document`.

In either case if I did or didn't, a few days to a week ago it was working fine and now the click event does not trigger anything when the items are clicked on.  I set up an `alert()` for testing it and nothing happens anymore.

Now to further test, I changed my `#taskWrap` back to `document` and the click event immediately strated working again!  So that does seem to be the issue.

Below is the code that I have now that does not work!  Below that is an image from Chrome Dev Tools that shows a little bit of the DOM structure for the area I am working with.

I am hoping someone can show me what I did wrong when trying to target my item using an ID that is closer to the target than `document` and `body` are?

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '#taskWrap .status_update', function(e) {

    alert('.status_update class checkbox task item clicked!');

});
```

I have also tried this with the same result, the click event does not happen...

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {

    alert('.status_update class checkbox task item clicked!');

});
```

This DOES Work but I am trying to better optimize by not having to use `document` or `body`

```
$('document').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {

    alert('.status_update class checkbox task item clicked!');

});
```

---

**UPDATE with more specific question...**

A Google search for what a Descendant is really considered in jQuery for the DOM had this result...

"A descendant is a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on. With jQuery you can traverse down the DOM tree to find descendants of an element."

so now im confused as I feel like `.status_update` should be considered a `great-great-grandchild` for #taskWrap.  Am I wrong here in this thinking?  IF so please help me to understand how it is not?

Based on the image below, to Traverse down the DOM from my `#taskWrap DIV` to ONE of my `.status_update DIV's` looks like this...

`#taskWrap > table.detail > tbody > td.task-checkbox > .status_update`

Please help me to understand where I am wrong and also what my jQuery should be replacing `#taskWrap` with to target my `.status_update` DIV's?

The image shows the `#taskWrap` DIV in relation to where the `.status_update` DIV Task Items I am clicking on are located...

[image]

---

**FINAL UPDATE WITH SOLUTION/ANSWER:**

It turns out with my recent restructuring my code, my click events got moved to a different file and they simply were not wrapped in DOC READY code...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    alert('DOM LOADED');
})
```

This solved my problem along with the obvious changing of this line like posted in the answers below...

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '#taskWrap .status_update', function(e) {
```

Changed to...

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {
```

Comment: The delegation selector only looks within your div's descendants - and there's no #taskWrap element there. Perhaps you meant to have just .status_update (quoting the jquery docs - "A selector string to filter the **descendants** of the selected elements that trigger the event")

Comment: @Sacho I guess the main source of the problem for me then is I am misunderstanding the term descendants as in the image, what I thought a descendant was, is basically a child item somewhere lower in the DOM.  You are saying it is not a descendant though, do you care to elaborate slightly if you are for it?  For something I work with daily, you would think I would know this =(

Comment: the delegation selector filters #taskWrap's descendants. Your delegation selector is "#taskWrap .status_update". This means "From #taskWrap's descendants, find the elements that have an id taskWrap. From their descendants, find the elements that have a class status_update". Obviously, none of #taskWrap's descendants have an id taskWrap.

Comment: @Sacho I have also tried this version which also does not work... `$('#taskWrap').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {` Like I mentioned in last comment it seems that I am not understanding what a `descendant` is considered as I thought it basically meant it was somewhere below the top items as a child somewhere along the line, possibly a child or grandchild, etc...it sounds like I am wrong in this thinking though.  To help me visualize better, looking at my image, what would be the next best ID to use for the target?

Comment: Does a `descendant` mean it can only be 1 level under the "parent"?

Comment: Actually a Google search just showed this answer "A descendant is a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on. With jQuery you can traverse down the DOM tree to find descendants of an element." so now im confused as I feel like `.status_update` should be considered one of those for `#taskWrap` but you said it is not

Comment: Looking at my image and going down the DOM it looks like this to me... `#taskWrap > table.detail > tbody > td.task-checkbox > .status_update` so how is `.status_update` not a descendant of `#taskWrap` ?  Would love any insight to this from anyone please?

Comment: .status_update is a descendant of #taskWrap. Try posting a jsfiddle with your specific issue - your question really has a lot of fluff unrelated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lies within your descendant selector. Your event handler binding should look like:

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {

    alert('.status_update class checkbox task item clicked!');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvbjn9wv/

This is because there is no `#taskWrap` descendant within the `#taskWrap` element.

Comment: Sorry I need to update my question to show that I also have tried to use `$('#taskWrap').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {` but it also does not work

Comment: Strange... It should be working. A JS Fiddle would be helpful here.  Let me whip one up.

Comment: Yes it is strange....I thought perhaps it is a caching issue on my end, so I just tried it in Chrome and made sure to load my JS file `CTRL+F5` for both my JavaScript file and then for the page itself that has the DOm items and loads in the JavaScript file.  I also view the updated JS file and I can see that it is serving my new updated version however it is not working for my click even.  I did the same thing for Firefox and IE and none worked!  I then tried in Chrome Incognito and for some reason, it IS working in that browser....continued...

Comment: ...I am not sure why I cannot get the others to work when they are serving the same updated JS file!  I have never had this strange issue until this week with this 1 click event

Comment: Very weird. I set up a fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/zvbjn9wv/

This is working as expected, so there must be some other variance that is breaking this. Are you able to create a JS fiddle of your own that reproduces this error? That way we can troubleshoot better.

Comment: I am going out on a limb to say it must in fact be some sort of freak caching issue on my end then.  What was even more strange is this is for a Project Management app with Tasks and on some projects it was working fine and on others it was not...as if certain projects were cached or something.  My original code in the question where I had `$('#taskWrap').on('click', '#taskWrap .status_update', function(e) {` I had only added `#taskWrap .status_update` for testing since my other correct version quite working...

Comment: ... Thanks for the help and clarifying that it was correct before I went and changed it all up.  Looks like my problem must be elsewhere!

Comment: No prob! Are there any JS errors on your console by any chance? This could cause a cascading effect, disabling other JS.

Comment: No errors but I found the problem...The click events in questions recently got moved around to different files and...they are not in a DOC READY type block, through them in a doc ready and everything back to normal!  Always something simple!  Thanks

Comment: On a page where it wasn't working, I copy/pasted the click event code into console and it then worked, thats how I tracked down that it must be loading before the actual DOmelements are seen

Comment: Good troubleshooting! Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `#taskWrap`

from this line:

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '#taskWrap .status_update', function(e) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

Correct line should be:

```
$('#taskWrap').on('click', '.status_update', function(e) {
```